# is there any nginx subdomain configuration for xyz websites?

Tags: nginx

I started using nginx but can't configure my files I added index.html on 
`/var/www/sub.domain.xyz/` (this is folder)
and added configurations on 
`/etc/nginx/sites-available/sub.domain.xyz` (this is file) and link it on '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/'

with the text below

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  root /var/www/sub.domain.xyz/;
  index index.html;
  server_name sub.domain.xyz;
}
```

and when I restart Nginx it always shows

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Please help. Thank you

[EDITED]

And this is what I got when I typed nginx

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.domain.xyz" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
```

Comment: Did you **See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details**?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes. status shows the error with exit code and failure on active status. journalctl shows authentication failure.

Comment: Nginx cannot read the file from the sites-enabled directory. Is the symlink correct?

Comment: @RichardSmith of course it is

Answer (score 0):

In some Distributions is it necessary to set a symbolic link from available to enabled.

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sub.domain.xyz /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.domain.xyz
```

For explanation of `ln -s` please take a look into the documenation of the **ln** command [man ln](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man1/ln.1.html)

Comment: I already used that to make a symbolic link. but still get that error